# MongoDB Aggregation Framework - Dynamic Field Rename

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am finding the MongoDB aggregation framework to be extremely powerful - it seems like a good option to flatten out an object. My schema uses a an array of sub objects in an array called `materials`. The number of `materials` is variable, but a specific field `category` will be unique across objects in the array. I would like to use the aggregation framework to flatten the structure and dynamically rename the fields based on the value of the `category` field. I could not find an easy way to accomplish this using a `$project` along with `$cond`. Is there a way?

The reason for the array of material objects is to allow simple searching:

e.g. `{ 'materials.name' : 'XYZ' }` pulls back any document where "XYZ" is found.

**E.g. of before and after document**

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("123456"),
"materials" : [
    {
        "name" : "XYZ",
        "type" : "Red",
        ...
        "category" : "A"
    },
    {
        "name" : "ZYX",
        "type" : "Blue",
        ...
        "category" : "B"
    }]
}
```

**to**

```
{
"material_A_name" : "XYZ",
"material_A_type" : "Red",
...
"material_B_name" : "ZYX",
"material_B_type" : "Blue",
...
}
```

Comment: Your 'after' document isn't valid JSON

Comment: Thanks, updated - it was an error from creating the mock-up in my editor

Comment: Ok, I see what you're trying to do now.  There's not much support for dynamically generated keys in the agg framework so I don't see how you could do this with that.  You may have to just post process the result in code to do it.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I do post process in python code now, but I was looking for an elegant/elegant way to create create an API to query mongo from another app that would query to view data in tabular form. e.g. the API would take connection details and an aggregation json string pipeline that produces flattened results to generate a tabular report.

Answer (score 6):

There is a request for something like this in jira https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5947 - vote it up if you would like to have this feature.

Meanwhile, there is a work-around if you know up front what the possible values of the keys will be (i.e. all unique values of "category") and I have some sample code on it [on my blog](http://www.kamsky.org/1/post/2013/04/using-aggregation-framework-to-reshape-schema.html).

Comment: Note that ability to transpose keys to values and vice versa has been available since MongoDB version 3.4.4.

Answer (score 3):

This would be useful from MongoDB v4.4,

- `$map` to iterate loop of `materials` array
- `$map` to iterate loop of `name` and `type` fields after converting to array using `$objectToArray`, concat your key fields requirement as per fields and value using `$concat`,
- back to first `$map` convert returned result from second `$map` from array to object using `$arrayToObject`
- `$unwind` deconstruct `materials` array
- `$group` by null and merge `materials` object to one object
- `$replaceRoot` to replace object in root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      materials: {
        $map: {
          input: "$materials",
          as: "m",
          in: {
            $arrayToObject: [
              {
                $map: {
                  input: {
                    $objectToArray: {
                      name: "$$m.name",
                      type: "$$m.type"
                    }
                  },
                  in: {
                    k: { $concat: ["material", "_", "$$m.category", "_", "$$this.k"] },
                    v: "$$this.v"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$materials" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      materials: { $mergeObjects: "$materials" }
    }
  },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$materials" } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7xzLA_3ie_q)