# Pivot rows to columns in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pivot

The relevant question is [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server-2008). But the answer is specific to SQL.

I want the same result i.e. pivot row to column without aggregating anything (as of now) in MongoDB.

The collection looks something as below. These are statistics of facebook page properties:

```
timestamp | propName | propValue
--------------------------------
1371798000000 | page_fans | 100
--------------------------------
1371798000000 | page_posts | 50
--------------------------------
1371798000000 | page_stories | 25
--------------------------------
```

I need answer like:

```
timestamp | page_fans | page_posts | page_stories
--------------------------------
1371798000000 | 100 | 50 | 25
--------------------------------
```

The column names are pre-determined. They don't have to be generated dynamically. But question is how to achieve this in MongoDB.

I believe aggregation is of no use for this purpose. Do I need to use MapReduce? But in that case I have nothing to reduce I guess? Well another option could be fetching these values in code and do the manipulation in programming language e.g. Java

Any insights would be helpful. Thanks in advance :)!!!

EDIT (Based on input from Schaliasos):

Input JSON:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("51cd366644aeac654ecf8f75"),
        "name" : "page_storytellers",
        "pageId" : "512f993a44ae78b14a9adb85",
        "timestamp" : NumberLong("1371798000000"),
        "value" : NumberLong(30871),
        "provider" : "Facebook"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("51cd366644aeac654ecf8f76"),
        "name" : "page_fans",
        "pageId" : "512f993a44ae78b14a9adb85",
        "timestamp" : NumberLong("1371798000000"),
        "value" : NumberLong(1291509),
        "provider" : "Facebook"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("51cd366644aeac654ecf8f77"),
        "name" : "page_fan_adds",
        "pageId" : "512f993a44ae78b14a9adb85",
        "timestamp" : NumberLong("1371798000000"),
        "value" : NumberLong(2829),
        "provider" : "Facebook"
}
```

Expected Output JSON:

```
{
        "timestamp" : NumberLong("1371798000000"),
        "provider" : "Facebook",
        "page_storytellers" : NumberLong(30871),
        "page_fans" : NumberLong("1371798000000"),
        "page_fan_adds" : NumberLong("1371798000000")
}
```

Comment: First of all, mongoDb has documents with a json format. Post the json you have and the json you want to get back so we understand it better. Second, why do you want that??

Comment: This is something definitely better done on the client side, I would not use the answer below to do this, it would not be very long until you get scaling problems with such queries.

Comment: For Dynamic filed names check [MongoDB Aggregation Framework - Dynamic Field Rename](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65246631/4732434)

Answer (score 13):

Now, you can utilise new aggregation [operator $arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) to pivot MongoDB keys. This operator is available in MongoDB v3.4.4+

For example, given an example data of:

```
db.foo.insert({ provider: "Facebook", timestamp: '1371798000000', name: 'page_storytellers', value: 20871})
db.foo.insert({ provider: "Facebook", timestamp: '1371798000000', name: 'page_fans', value: 1291509})
db.foo.insert({ provider: "Facebook", timestamp: '1371798000000', name: 'page_fan_adds', value: 2829})
db.foo.insert({ provider: "Google", timestamp: '1371798000000', name: 'page_fan_adds', value: 1000})
```

You can utilise [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) below:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
  {$group:
     {_id:{provider:"$provider", timestamp:"$timestamp"}, 
      items:{$addToSet:{name:"$name",value:"$value"}}}
  }, 
  {$project:
     {tmp:{$arrayToObject: 
       {$zip:{inputs:["$items.name", "$items.value"]}}}}
  }, 
  {$addFields:
     {"tmp.provider":"$_id.provider", 
      "tmp.timestamp":"$_id.timestamp"}
  }, 
  {$replaceRoot:{newRoot:"$tmp"}
  }
]);
```

The output would be:

```
{
  "page_fan_adds": 1000,
  "provider": "Google",
  "timestamp": "1371798000000"
},
{
  "page_fan_adds": 2829,
  "page_fans": 1291509,
  "page_storytellers": 20871,
  "provider": "Facebook",
  "timestamp": "1371798000000"
}
```

See also [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/),
[$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/),
[$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/),
[$zip](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/zip/),
 and [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/)

Comment: This is a better answer.

Comment: This is Jedi-level aggreagtion framework mastery. Thank you for this!

Comment: Thanks! Great answer. Looks like we can skip the `$zip` if we `$addToSet` and create the format required by `$arrayToObject`. I used the `{k: "$name", v: "$value"}` format. [Example here.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zAHWAj8fSqG)

Answer (score 11):

I have done something like this using aggregation. Could this help ?

```
db.foo.insert({ timestamp: '1371798000000', propName: 'page_fans', propValue: 100})
db.foo.insert({ timestamp: '1371798000000', propName: 'page_posts', propValue: 25})
db.foo.insert({ timestamp: '1371798000000', propName: 'page_stories', propValue: 50})

db.foo.aggregate({ $group: { _id: '$timestamp', result: { $push: { 'propName': '$propName', 'propValue': '$propValue' } }}})

{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : "1371798000000",
            "result" : [
                {
                    "propName" : "page_fans",
                    "propValue" : 100
                },
                {
                    "propName" : "page_posts",
                    "propValue" : 50
                },
                {
                    "propName" : "page_stories",
                    "propValue" : 25
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

You may want to use `$sum` operator along the way. See [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/group/)

Comment: Looks interesting. This was one of my ideas, but problem is I need to generate daily charts based on specific properties and their values. Obtaining a result like this would still require some additional processing in code which I want to avoid. I'll see though if I can fit this somewhere. Thanks for replying.

Comment: You welcome. Please consider at least up voting if you think this do not answer completely your question ;) Good luck.

Comment: Sorry, did that now. I think I can utilize above by getting the output and formatting in server side service and returning result to client in format that can be utilized for charting.
Will wait if someone has better alternative to offer. Thanks again!!!

Comment: Just thought about it, using `map_reduce` could be a good idea if you need to generate daily charts