# Change field name in result Mongo Query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this Mongo query:

```
db.getCollection('Catalogos').aggregate(
     { $match: {Items: {$elemMatch: {'MarIclase': '04'} } } }, 
     { $unwind : "$Items" },
     { $match: { "Items.MarIclase" : "04" } },
     { $group : { 
         _id : "$_id", 
         Items : { $push : { 'MarIclase': "$Items.MarIclase", 'MarCdescrip' : '$Items.MarCdescrip' } } 
     }}
);
```

The result of this query is:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "CAT_MARCAS_VU",
            "Items" : [ 
                {
                    "MarIclase" : "04",
                    "MarCdescrip" : "5500 LARSON"
                }, 
                {
                    "MarIclase" : "04",
                    "MarCdescrip" : "A LINER"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

I'd like to have this result:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "CAT_MARCAS_VU",
            "Items" : [ 
                {
                    "04" : "5500 LARSON"
                }, 
                {
                    "04" : "A LINER"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

¿Do you know if I can make something in the $push and change the fieldnames for values?

I'd like to have something like this:

```
{ "04" : "A LINER" }
{ "04" : "5500 LARSON" }
```

Thank you!

Comment: See https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5947 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754558/mongodb-aggregation-framework-dynamic-field-rename