# Mongodb Aggregate query to sum all values based on fields inside objects in an Array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

I have a collection `data` in MongoDB which looks like this -

document 1-

```
{
    metadata:[
        {
            "title": "High",
            "val": 12
        },
        {
            "title": "Medium",
            "val": 15
        },
        {
            "title": "Low",
            "val": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

document2 -

```
{
    metadata:[
        {
            "title": "High",
            "val": 10
        },
        {
            "title": "Medium",
            "val": 12
        },
        {
            "title": "Low",
            "val": 20
        }
    ]
}
```

& so on..

I wish to aggregate the `val` field based on the `title` value.
The output should look like -

```
{
    "High": 22,
    "Medium": 27,
    "Low": 22
}
```

How do I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$unwind` deconstruct `metadata` array
- `$grpup` by `title` and make sum of `val`
- `$group` by null, convert array to object from key and value by `$arrayToObject`, and merge objects using `$mergeObjects`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$metadata" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$metadata.title",
      sum: { $sum: "$metadata.val" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      metadata: {
        $mergeObjects: {
          $arrayToObject: [
            [{ k: "$_id", v: "$sum" }]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iDsHqvl0aiu)

Comment: I get this error when I try to run this query on actual data - $arrayToObject requires an object with keys 'k' and 'v', where the value of 'k' must be of type string. Found type: null

Comment: there would be some null or empty value in title or val fields. can you make sure where is it?

Comment: figured out. error was from my end. thanks!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can first $unwind the `metadata` array. Then use $group and $cond to $sum your values.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$metadata"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      High: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "$metadata.title",
                "High"
              ]
            },
            "$metadata.val",
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      Medium: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "$metadata.title",
                "Medium"
              ]
            },
            "$metadata.val",
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      Low: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "$metadata.title",
                "Low"
              ]
            },
            "$metadata.val",
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hlFUljft8aa) for your reference.

Comment: thanks!! is there a way to achieve this when we do not know the field values High, Medium, Low by segregating based on unique title values?

Comment: @Ray that was too old post, for the latest version it is possible, i have just answered there [take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65246631/8987128)

Comment: @turivishal yes you are right, your answer should be the accepted one :)